# Call function from another file without import clause?

Tags: python

Is is possible to call a function from another file without placing `from import` clause? I'd like to write Python code shorter and cleaner here, so I'm curious if there is a way to do that.

For example, usually we write like this and this works:

```py
from tmpapp.forms import KakikomiForm

def kakikomi(request):
    f = KakikomiForm()
```

I'd like to write something like this if possible, but this will be error:

```py
# from tmpapp.forms import KakikomiForm

def kakikomi(request):
    f = tmpapp.forms.KakikomiForm()
```

Comment: For many languages that I've seen, there often has to be a way for the language/interpreter/compiler to find the definitions for functions that are called. Even when using a standard library module like `re` (ref: Python `re` docs), it usually needs to be imported at some point before use. Built-in items seem to be able to be used without doing an explicit import statement, but for user defined functions, I think you'll want to use some sort of import statement. I think it helps with clarity, even if it takes more lines of code; it can help one know where something comes from in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any importing this is **not** possible, but what you **can** do is, import a module, and call a function of a submodule of that module. Like this:

```py
import tmpapp
def kakikomi(request):
    f = tmpapp.forms.KakikomiForm()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, in some way... You can load the module using importlib, find the function and call it. Suppose we have following project structure:

```
your_project/
├── some_lib
│   └── some_module.py
└── test_dyn_import.py
```

where `some_module.py` contains the function `print_args` we want to call without "import":

```py
# Somewhere in some_module.py
def print_args(*argv):
    for v in argv:
        print(v)
```

Then helping function `call_func` and caller's code will be:

```py
# test_dyn_import.py
import importlib
from inspect import isfunction

def call_func(full_module_name, func_name, *argv):
    module = importlib.import_module(full_module_name)
    for attribute_name in dir(module):
        attribute = getattr(module, attribute_name)
        if isfunction(attribute) and attribute_name == func_name:
            attribute(*argv)


call_func('some_lib.some_module', 'print_args', 'foo', 'bar', 101)
```

And the output will be

```sh
your_project/venv/bin/python test_dyn_import.py
foo
bar
101
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a name fully qualified, you can use `import` rather than `from ... import`.

```
import tmpapp.forms

def kakikomi(request):
    f = tmpapp.forms.KakikomiForm()
```

But the `import` is still strictly necessary, as it tells Python to go and physically load the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use classes/functions from another modules(files) without importing them.